# Is it possible to distinguish Bool and Int in Swift?

Tags: swift, integer, boolean

I have an `AnyObject` type that can be `String`, `Int` or `Bool` type. I need to distinguish them.

This code tries to do so, but it considers `Bool` to be `Int`:

```
import Cocoa

var value: AnyObject

func checkType(value: AnyObject) -> String {
    if let intvalue: Int = value as? Int {
        return("It is an integer")
    } else if let boolvalue: Bool = value as? Bool {
        return("It is an boolean")
    } else if let stringvalue: String = value as? String {
        return("It is an string")
    }
    return "not found"
}

value = "hello"
checkType(value) // It is an string

value = 1
checkType(value) // It is an integer

value = true
checkType(value) // It is an integer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
func checkType<T>(value: T) -> String {
    var statusText = "not found"
    if value is Int {
        statusText = "It is an integer"
    } else if value is Bool {
        statusText = "It is an boolean"
    } else if value is String {
        statusText = "It is an string"
    }
    return statusText
}
```

`AnyObject` cannot be implicitly downcast to any type in Swift. For such case you can use `Generics` instead.

> Generic code enables you to write flexible, reusable functions and types that can work with any type, subject to requirements that you define. [Read more](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html).

Comment: checkType(true) returns "it is an integer"

Comment: Generics is unnecessary here. `value` can just be type `Any`.

Comment: this will not work for AnyObject as it can be cast to either Int or Bool

Answer (score 0):

The way worked with me is by using the **Mirror** struct.

```
let value: Any? = 867
let stringMirror = Mirror(reflecting: value!)
let type = stringMirror.subjectType
print(stringMirror.subjectType)

if type == Bool.self {
    print("type is Bool")
} else if type == String.self {
    print("type is string")
} else if type == Int.self {
    print("type is Int")
}
```

use **Any** here since *Int, String, Bool* are structs. 
if you just try to distinguish between classes using **is** should work.

```
if value is NSString {
    print("type is NSString")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To distinguish Bool from `Int` (in pure Swift and ObjC bridging) one can use the following extension for `AnyHashable`

```
extension AnyHashable {

    var isBool: Bool {
        Bool(description) != nil && !(self is String)
    }

    var boolValue: Bool? {
        isBool ? (self as? Bool) : nil
    }
}
```

Here we check description which is `true/false` for Bool-like value and then exclude the same String-like value.

It is common case to get data collection (e.g. json) and cast it as `AnyHashable`.

The same works for `NSNumber`.