# Type checks on Int and Bool values are returning incorrectly in Swift 4.2

Tags: swift

I currently have an issue with Swift 4.2 that I wanted to ask for peoples help addressing.

At the moment, I am deserializing a JSON response, which is a dictionary whose keys are of type `String` and whose values can be of type `Int` or `Bool`. A good example is the following:

```
{
    "number_of_likes": 0,
    "is_liked": true

}
```

When I deserialize the object, the JSON response is of type `[String: Any]`, which is expected.

The task:
I need to create an array detailing which keys are of type `Bool` and set to `true`.

The problem:

When running the following code using the response highlighted above:

```
guard let json = json as? [String: Any] else {
    return
}

for key in dict.keys {

    print("KEY: \(key)")

    let value = dict[key]

    if value is Int {
        print("It is an integer")
    }

    if value is Bool {
        print("It is a bool")
    }

}
```

return strings

The console prints this:

```
 t+20.765 KEY: number_of_likes
 t+20.765 It is an integer
 t+20.765 It is a bool

 t+20.765 KEY: is_liked
 t+20.765 It is an integer
 t+20.765 It is a bool
```

As you can see, the **0** `Int` value is causing the console to print that it is of type Bool and Int, while the **true** Bool value is causing the console to print that it is of type `Int` and `Bool`.

For context, I did find the following question on StackOverflow, but the answer did not work unless I check for type `CFBool` as opposed to type `Bool`.

[Is it possible to distinguish Bool and Int in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28921378/is-it-possible-to-distinguish-bool-and-int-in-swift)

Can someone please tell me if I am doing something wrong, or if this is an issue with Swift 4.2?

I definitely appreciate the help, so thank you for all who read this.

Comment: Your code as shown is insufficient to explain your claimed output. Please show real and complete code. Start with the actual JSON string and show how you get `json` from it. You should be using Decodable, but it seems you are not.

Comment: Apart from your output shouldn't you know whether a key will be a bool or Int in advance and hardCode it accordingly ??

Comment: What is `dict`? Use structs instead of dictionaries

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sadly, you can't solve this without going down to a pretty low level, using either Core Foundation types or Objective-C `@encode` strings.

The problem is that, under the covers, Foundation's JSON serialization uses `NSNumber` to wrap both integers and booleans. So the JSON `0` and the JSON `true` are both converted to `NSNumber` objects, and Swift is willing to convert either of those `NSNumber` objects to an `Int` or a `Bool` on request.

However, the JSON booleans are in fact converted to a subclass of `NSNumber` called `__NSCFBoolean`, which is the type that a `CFBooleanRef` (in Swift, `CFBoolean`) references:

```
import Foundation

let json = """
{
    "number_of_likes": 0,
    "is_liked": true

}
"""

let data = json.data(using: .utf8)!
let jso = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [String: Any]

for key in jso.keys {
    if let value = jso[key] as? NSNumber {
        print("\(key) \(type(of: value)) \(String(cString: value.objCType))")
    }
}
```

Output:

```
number_of_likes __NSCFNumber q
is_liked __NSCFBoolean c
```

It's not documented that Foundation JSON serialization decodes JSON booleans to Core Foundation `CFBoolean`s, but it's unlikely to change.

So here's a Core Foundation way to test:

```
if let isLikedCF = jso["is_liked"] as CFTypeRef?,
    CFGetTypeID(isLikedCF) == CFBooleanGetTypeID()
{
    print("it's bool")
} else {
    print("it's not bool")
}
```

What we're doing here is converting the value from the JSON dictionary to a `CFTypeRef` (which is a reference to any Core Foundation type, and everything returned by Foundation's `JSONSerialization` is toll-free bridged to a Core Foundation type), and then checking whether the Core Foundation object's type ID is the `CFBoolean` type ID.

Another way to test using Core Foundation is to recognize that there are only two `CFBooleanRef` values, `kCFBooleanTrue` and `kCFBooleanFalse`. You can see if `jso["is_liked"] as? NSNumber` is identical to one of those two values, using `===`:

```
if let isLikedNumber = jso["is_liked"] as? NSNumber,
    isLikedNumber === kCFBooleanTrue || isLikedNumber === kCFBooleanFalse
{
    print("it's bool")
} else {
    print("it's not bool")
}
```

You can also test by checking the `NSNumber`'s Objective-C type code. You cast `jso["is_liked"] as? NSNumber`, ask for its `objCType`, convert the resulting C-string to a Swift `String`, and compare it to `"c"`. If so, it's a boolean. Otherwise, it's not.

```
if let isLikedNumber = jso["is_liked"] as? NSNumber {
    if String(cString: isLikedNumber.objCType) == "c" {
        print("it's bool")
    } else {
        print("it's not bool")
    }
}
```

The `c` comes from `@encode(BOOL)` (in Objective-C), where `BOOL` is a typedef of `signed char`. This is really obscure stuff. I'd recommend going with a Core Foundation test (shown above), since it's easier to understand and better documented.

Comment: Awesome detailed explanation. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like this

```
import UIKit

var str = """
{
"number_of_likes": 0,
"is_liked": true
}
"""
struct JsonStruct: Decodable {
    var boolWithKey: [String: Bool]?
    var intWithKey: [String: Int]?
    init(from decoder: Decoder) {
        guard let container = try? decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self) else {
            fatalError()
        }
        for key in container.allKeys {
            if let possibleInt = try? container.decode(Int.self, forKey: key) {
                intWithKey = [key.stringValue: possibleInt]
            }
            if let possibleBool = try? container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: key) {
                boolWithKey = [key.stringValue: possibleBool]
            }
        }
        print(container.allKeys)
    }

    struct CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        var stringValue: String
        init?(stringValue: String) {
            self.stringValue = stringValue
        }
        var intValue: Int?
        init?(intValue: Int) {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
let jsonData = str.data(using: .utf8)!
let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
let jsonStruct = try! jsonDecoder.decode(JsonStruct.self, from: jsonData)
print("\(jsonStruct.boolWithKey)")
print("\(jsonStruct.intWithKey)")
```

Output:

> CodingKeys(stringValue: "number_of_likes", intValue: nil),
>
> CodingKeys(stringValue: "is_liked", intValue: nil)]
>
> Optional(["is_liked": true])
>
> Optional(["number_of_likes": 0])

Comment: He doesn’t need to do that. His types are not actually dynamic. He has described the problem incorrectly.